# Dos str.split seguidos

Tags: python

Tengo una serie de datos ordenados tal que:

> {"PseudorangeRateUncertaintyMetersPerSecond": 0.1289496429081,
>   "DriftUncertaintyNanosPerSecond": "", "AccumulatedDeltaRangeState": 1,
>   "ReceivedSvTimeNanos": 491721930367520.0, "TimeUncertaintyNanos": "",
>   "SnrInDb": "", "FullBiasNanos": -1.2125108815424e+18, "State": 47,
>   "MultipathIndicator": "0", "AgcDb": "",
>   "PseudorangeRateMetersPerSecond": -80.016064827732, "TimeNanos":
>   40458000000, "Svid": 10, "AccumulatedDeltaRangeUncertaintyMeters":
>   0.002334289252758, "AccumulatedDeltaRangeMeters": -3022.5235041815, "BiasUncertaintyNanos": 5.3149323606571, "BiasNanos": 0,
>   "CarrierPhaseUncertainty": "", "CarrierFrequencyHz2": "\n",
>   "TimeOffsetNanos": 0, "DriftNanosPerSecond": "", "CarrierFrequencyHz":
>   "", "ConstellationType": "1", "CarrierCycles": "",
>   "ReceivedSvTimeUncertaintyNanos": 25, "CarrierPhase": "",
>   "LeapSecond": "", "HardwareClockDiscontinuityCount": 0,
>   "ElapsedRealtimeMillis": 14068886, "Id": "Raw", "Cn0DbHz":
>   31.292695999146} {"GPS_time": "2018-06-08 16:35:24", "Altitude": 70.768542, "Longitude": -0.337611, "Provider": "gps", "Latitude": 39.479199, "Speed": 0, "Id": "Fix", "Accuracy": 4} {"Number_of_sentences_for_full_data": 4, "Elevation_Degrees": 14,
>   "Azimuth_degrees": 62, "Sentence_1_of_2": 3,
>   "Number_of_satellites_in_view": 14, "Satellite_PRN_number": 21, "SNR":
>   "33", "CheckSum_data": 7, "Satellites_in_view": "$GPGSV", "Id": "NMEA
>   GSV"} {"Latitud": 3928.752338, "HorizontalDilutionofPosition": 0.4,
>   "TimeinSecondsSinceLastDGPSUpdate": "51.1", "Direccion_longitud": "W",
>   "GlobalPositioningSystemFixData": "$GPGGA", "Direccion_Latitud": "N",
>   "FixQuality": 1, "DGPSStationIDNumber": "51.1", "Altitude": 19.6,
>   "Geoid_height_units": "M", "ChecksumData": "M",
>   "Fixtakenat_hh_mm_ss_UTC": 163508, "NumberofSatellitesTracked": 30,
>   "Geoid_height": 51.1, "Altitude_units": "M", "Id": "NMEA GGA",
>   "Longitud": 20.256369}

El programa que yo tengo me los separa por "," pero necesito también separarlos por ":" si no puedo acceder a esos valores.

```
linea=r.readline()
if not linea:break
lect_linea=linea.split(',')
```

Answer (score 1):

`str.split` retorna una lista con las distintas subcadenas resultado de dividir por el separador:

```
>>> linea = '"A": 0.12, "B": 2.5, "C": 1'
>>> linea.split(",")
['"A": 0.12', ' "B": 2.5', ' "C": 1']
```

Para dividir también por ":" solo tendrías que aplicar `str.split` sobre cada ítem de la lista resultado de aplicar `split(",")` iterando sobre ella, por ejemplo usando listas por compresión:

```
>>> linea = '"A": 0.12, "B": 2.5, "C": 1'
>>> r = [pareja.split(": ") for pareja in linea.split(", ")]
>>> r
[['"A"', '0.12'], ['"B"', '2.5'], ['"C"', '1']]
```

Si se necesita dividir por varios separadores al mismo tiempo se puede usar `re.split` en vez de `str.split`:

```
>>> import re
>>> linea = '"A": 0.12, "B": 2.5, "C": 1'
>>> res = re.split(r',\s|:\s', linea)
>>> res
['"A"', '0.12', '"B"', '2.5', '"C"', '1']
```

Dado que aparentemente estás intentando parsear lo que es un diccionario Python válido o un archivo JSON válido, hay formas más eficientes de hacerlo:

- Usar `ast.literal_eval` (cualquier representación válida de un diccionario Python):

  ```
  >>> from ast import literal_eval
  >>> texto = '{"A": 0.12, "B": 2.5, "C": 1}'
  >>> diccionario = literal_eval(texto)
  >>> diccionario
  {'A': 0.12, 'B': 2.5, 'C': 1}
  >>> diccionario["B"]
  2.5
  ```
- Usar `json.loads` (JSON válido):

  ```
  >>> import json
  >>> texto = '{"A": 0.12, "B": 2.5, "C": 1}'
  >>> diccionario = json.loads(texto)
  >>> diccionario
  {'A': 0.12, 'B': 2.5, 'C': 1}
  >>> diccionario["C"]
  1
  ```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Props por mencionar `ast.literal_eval`