# string to list en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Hola Como puedo convertir ***string*** '[1,2,3,4]' a lista **list** en python teniendo lo siguiente

```
valor_inicial = str([1,2,3])
```

deseo ahora ese valor_inicial convertirlo en lista.Como lo puedo hacer?

Comment: ¿Quieres convertir una cadena de la forma `"[1, 2, 3]"` a una lista de enteros `[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: si asi es aunque ya encontré y publique posibles soluciones si hay alguna mejor es bienvenida

Comment: Las dos formas que muestras son las mejores para esto en principio, yo prefiero `ast` en términos generales porque es válida para cualquier cadena que represente una lista Python, usando `json` no siempre es así, por ejemplo: `valor_inicial = "['c', 'b', 'c']"` no es sintaxis válida para un json por el uso de las comillas simples, pero es la representación válida de una lista de cadenas. Esta pregunta está relacionada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/178091/dos-str-split-seguidos/178097#178097, en este caso es un diccionario pero la idea es la misma. Un saludo.

Comment: de acuerdo gracias por tu aclaración de igual manera un Saludo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ya lo logre encontré 2 alternativas:

**primero:**

```
valor_inicial = str([1,2,3])

import json
json.loads(valor_inicial)
```

**segundo:**

```
from ast import literal_eval

valor_inicial = str([1,2,3])
literal_eval(valor_inicial)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(map(int, "[1,2,3]".replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(',')))
```

- Quitamos los `"["` y  `"]"`
- Hacemos un `split()` por la `,` para obtener una lista
- Solo falta convertir cada elemento en un `int`, lo hacemos con `map(lista, int)`

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la manera mas sencilla:

```
x = str([1,2,3]) # Devuelve "[1,2,3]" (string)
y = eval(x) # Devuelve [1,2,3] (list)
```

La función predefinida **eval(str)** evalúa la expresión dentro de una cadena.